# Manipulate Seq Elements in an Akka Flow

Tags: akka-stream

I have 2 flows like the following:

```
val aToSeqOfB: Flow[A, Seq[B], NotUsed] = ...
val bToC: Flow[B, C, NotUsed] = ...
```

I want to combine these into a convenience method like the following:

```
val aToSeqOfC: Flow[A, Seq[C], NotUsed]
```

So far I have the following, but I know it just ends up with `C` elements and not `Seq[C]`.

```
Flow[A].via(aToSeqOfB).mapConcat(_.toList).via(bToC)
```

How can I preserve the `Seq` in this scenario?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Indirect Answer**

In my opinion your question highlights one of the "rookie mistakes" that is common when dealing with akka streams.  It is usually not good organization to put business logic within akka stream constructs.  Your question indicates that you have something of the form:

```
val bToC : Flow[B, C, NotUsed] = Flow[B] map { b : B => 
  //business logic
}
```

The more ideal scenario would be if you had:

```
//normal function, no akka involved
val bToCFunc : B => C = { b : B =>
  //business logic
}

val bToCFlow : Flow[B,C,NotUsed] = Flow[B] map bToCFunc
```

In the above "ideal" example the `Flow` is just a thin veneer on top of normal, non-akka, business logic.

The separate logic can then simply solve your original question with:

```
val aToSeqOfC : Flow[A, Seq[C], NotUsed] = 
  aToSeqOfB via (Flow[Seq[B]] map (_ map bToCFunc))
```

**Direct Answer**

If you cannot reorganize your code then the only available option is to deal with Futures.  You'll need to use `bToC` within a separate sub-stream:

```
val mat : akka.stream.Materializer = ???

val seqBToSeqC : Seq[B] => Future[Seq[C]] = 
  (seqB) =>
    Source
      .apply(seqB.toIterable)
      .via(bToC)
      .to(Sink.seq[C])
      .run()
```

You can then use this function within a `mapAsync` to construct the Flow you are looking for:

```
val parallelism = 10

val aToSeqOfC: Flow[A, Seq[C], NotUsed] = 
  aToSeqB.mapAsync(parallelism)(seqBtoSeqC)
```

Comment: In my code `seqBToSeqC` does not compile. It says the `Source.apply(_)` signature is invalid.

Comment: It compiles for me but answer ammended.

Comment: Tried that. Same with the no signature. Type mismatch expected `Iterable[NotInferedT]` actual `Seq[B]`

Comment: Oh, I guess it wants `Source(seqB.toList)`

Comment: @RachelG. I would do `.toIterable` instead.